Использование метода map
Здраствуйте. Я пытаюсь получить примерный результат как на этом фото. Но у меня это не получается.

это то что сделало ячейку красной
  className={'tuesday'==subject.day&&5==subject.lesson&&'active'}


Но будет ли ячейка красной по идеи, должно зависеть от ключей внутри sl массива внутри которого объекты содержащие ключи day и lesson. То есть например вместо tuesday может быть friday или monday в зависимости от того есть ли это свойство внутри sl
subject это каждая (отдельный объект) td ячейка (кроме th элементов) которая содержит данные day, lesson, id и тд.

то есть если day и lesson у subject будет равно day и lesson y sl то класс ячейки становится active.  Такова логика. Но реализовать ее не удается. У меня даже нет идей как это решить.
export const Subjects = ({ subject, changeSub, sl }) => {
    // console.log(sl.day==subject.day&&sl.lesson==subject.lesson);
    console.log(sl);
    console.log(subject);
    // console.log(sl.map(sl=>(sl.day==subject.day&&sl.lesson==subject.lesson)));
    return (
        <td
            className={'tuesday'==subject.day&&5==subject.lesson&&'active'}
            onClick={(e) => changeSub(e, subject)}
            key={subject._id}>
            {subject.subject} {subject.teacherNum}
        </td>
    );
};


Компонента Subjects это каждая ячейка
sl.map(sl=>(sl.day==subject.day&&sl.lesson==subject.lesson))

Этот код сработал следующим образом.


и когда я поставил его как условие для active класса для элемента td все ячейки стали красными. Я конечно понимал что он не сработает. Я просто хочел показать что выводит тот или иной код.
import React from "react";
import { Subjects } from "../Subjects/Subjects";

export const SchDay = ({day, index, schedule, changeSub, sl}) => {
   console.log(sl);
   return (
       <tr key={day}>
           <th>{schedule[day] && schedule.days[index]}</th>
           {schedule[day] && schedule[day].length > 0 ? (
               schedule[day].map((subject) =>
                   {
                       sl.map(sl=>
                           <Subjects subject={subject} changeSub={changeSub} sl={sl} />
                       )
                   }
               )
           ) : (
               <td>Предмет</td>
           )}
       </tr>
   );
};

Вот что получится если сделать так как показано выше


В чем именно вопрос? Что не получается? Или просто кодом хвастаетесь...?

ой да я кажется забыл прояснить

а в чем проблема передать sl={{ day: stateDay, lesson: stateLesson }} , где stateDay и stateLesson определяются где-то выше в состояниях?

@Arbery если бы у stateDay и stateLesson было только одно значение было бы проще. но у них несколько значений. а для это нужно пройтись по ним тоесть mapить. но у меня есть другой массив откуда я через map получаю subject. и получается мне нужно внутри этого map сделать еще один map другого массива чтобы получить каждый stateDay и stateLesson? я это пробовал но в результате ничего не выводится совсем

а в каком виде эти самые несколько значений? массив? - ну значит includes вместо ==

@Arbery Типа sl=[{ day: stateDay, lesson: stateLesson },{ day: stateDay, lesson: stateLesson },{ day: stateDay, lesson: stateLesson }, и тд] Хорошо сейчас попробую

@Arbery сработал этот метод sl.some(guest => guest.day === subject.day&&guest.lesson === subject.lesson) спасибо вам
